# Replacing values in particular row with another row in R language

Tags: r

I have matrix and i want to replace the fourth row enteries with the 1st row values. Which R command would help me?
I am using replace command but its giving me dimension error.

```
> replace(g1,g[1,],g[2,])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    4    2    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    5    6    0    1    2    3    4
[3,]    6    5    6    0    1    2    3
[4,]    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: `g1[4,]=g1[1,]`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it without use any external functions:

```
g1[4,] <- g1[1,]
```

Taking all the columns values for the 4th row and replace it with the first row.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use `replace`, you can try the code below

```
g1 <- replace(g1,row(g1)==4,g1[1,])
```

Otherwise, `g1[4,] <- g[1,]` would be enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot..i chose the second option